# How to root and install TWRP on LG G3

Tags: rooting, root-access, twrp, lg-g3, lineageos

I would like to install LineageOS on my LG G3 d855.
Therefore I need to install TWRP.
Therefore I need to root my device.

I am running an ubuntu laptop and tried to use PurpleDrake-Lite but it ended up with the fallowing log:

```
chmod: cannot access './assets/linux/': No such file or directory
Launching PurpleDrake for Linux


Welcome to PurpleDrake!

Please ensure your phone is connected, powered on, and USB debugging is properly enabled.
Your phone should be showing your homescreen with no other apps open. This is to ensure a clean state.
When you're ready, press [enter]...

Press [enter] to continue...
Waiting for device... . Found device! 


Your phone is a [ LG-D855 ] on [ VDF ] running SW version [ V30n ] ...


Alright. We're ready to go. We're going to temproot your phone first. Press enter when you're ready!
Press [enter] to continue...

Rebooting phone...
Waiting for device... ....... Found device! 
Found device, checking if vulnerable...

ERROR: Your phone is not running a compatible software version. No vulnerable mode detected, rebooting phone.
We tried to temproot you, and it didn't work. This phone isn't vulnerable, it would appear.
Please post on XDA with your phone model, carrier, and SW version in the PurpleDrake thread and someone will take a look.
Your phone has been rebooted back to normal system mode, no changes have been made. Thanks for trying!
```

Well I am wondering about the really first line. PurperlDrake tried to change permissions on assets/linix. I checked out this directory, but there is only linux32 and linux64. I am totally confused what to do next. Rooting my old Nexus device was pretty easy done by the adb tools. But the LG G3 seems to be much harder to root.

What is the right way to root my LG G3?

Comment: You see, LG phones usually don't have an unlockable bootloader. Devs find ways to work that around, but usually requires the phone itself to be rooted prior to flashing TWRP, via another means. You might wanna search around XDA for more clues.

Comment: Ok, well I searched around for a while and found hundred of different solutions but most of them do not work for 30n. I found now this: https://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/general/guide-how-to-root-twrp-lg-g3-d855-v30n-t3507306 it is for windows, so I'll need to search for my old Windows Laptop...